# Tráfego de pacotes na rede

Tags: redes

Há muito tempo atrás, tive conhecimento de uma técnica que basicamente todo o dado que é enviado ou recebido pelo roteador, é **"duplicado" e encaminhado para um endereço específico** e o endereço remetente/destinatário original óbvio. 
Obviamente isso causa uma sobrecarga nesse endereço específico e isso é utilizado por maliciosos p/ acessar os dados mas também propositalmente para verificar a integridade dos pacotes. 
Minha dúvida é: Qual o nome dessa "técnica"?

Comment: Broadcast, Seria isso?

Comment: Não sei muito sobre redes mas o que eu buscava se chama Sniffer

Comment: Sniffer é verficar todos os pacotes que estão passando na rede incluindo os que não são destinados a vc. Broadcast é quando vc envia um ou mais pacotes para todos os hosts na rede.

Comment: Se for um switch você pode alcançar isto fazendo "Port mirroring", na qual todo o tráfego é encaminhado para uma porta especifica em que você tem um equipamento sniffando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez a técnica "man-in-the-middle" seja o que você procura, já que há um "sniffer pivot" entre o remetente e o destinatário do pacote, onde esse "pivot" é responsável por receber o pacote enviado, fazer o que for preciso com o mesmo e enviar para o destino. Caso precise de mais informações, pode ler aqui: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack